# Mixing Ruby and bash commands -- mv returns "x and y are the same file"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash, shell

So I have a Ruby script (using Ruby because we have a library of pre-existing code that I need to use). From within Ruby I am using backticks to call Linux commands, specifically in this case the "mv" command. I am trying to move one file to another location but I keep getting the error message that x and y are "the same file" even though they are very clearly NOT the same file.

Here is the code in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby

masterFiles=[]
masterFiles << "/mnt/datadrive/Data Capture/QualityControl/UH_HRA_SVY/Scans and DataOutput/Data/UH_HRA_SVY_DATA.txt"
masterFiles << "/mnt/datadrive/Data Capture/QualityControl/UH_HRA_SVY_SPAN/Scans and DataOutput/Data/UH_HRA_SVY_SPAN_DATA.txt"

tm=Time.new.strftime("%Y%m%d")

masterFiles.each do |mf|
  if File.exist?(mf)
    qmf=39.chr + mf + 39.chr
    `cat #{qmf} >> /tmp/QM`
    savename=39.chr + \
      "/mnt/datadrive/Data Capture/QualityControl/UH_HRA_SVY/Scans and DataOutput/Data/DailyFiles/" + \
      File.basename(mf).gsub(".txt","_"+tm) + ".txt" + 39.chr
    `mv #{qmf} #{savename}`
  end
end
```

The error that I get is this:

> `` mv: `/mnt/datadrive/Data Capture/QualityControl/UH_HRA_SVY_SPAN/Scans
>   and DataOutput/Data/UH_HRA_SVY_SPAN_DATA.txt' and `/mnt/datadrive/Data
>   Capture/QualityControl/UH_HRA_SVY/Scans and
>   DataOutput/Data/DailyFiles/UH_HRA_SVY_SPAN_DATA_20140530.txt' are the
>   same file ``

If I change this line:

```
`mv #{qmf} #{savename}`
```

To this:

```
puts "mv #{qmf} #{savename}"
```

And then run the output, it works as expected.

I am pretty sure that this has to do with spaces in the path. I have tried every combination of double-quoting, triple-quoting, quadruple-quoting, and back-slashing I can think of to resolve this but no go. I have also tried using FileUtils.mv but get what is basically the same error worded differently.

Can anybody help ? Thanks a lot.

p.s. I realize it's entirely possible that I could be going about this in an entirely wrong-headed way, so feel free to point that out if so. However, I am trying to use the tools which I already have some knowledge of (cat, mv, etc) instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: You've got spaces in your filenames, and since you're calling out to the command line `mv`, those spaces are going to be considered argument separators, not part of your filenames.

Comment: Mayby try using `FileUtils.mv` instead of running it with `\`` method?

Comment: Or `mv #{qmf.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} ...` etc. Or `mv "#{qmf}" "#{savename}"` works for me (not sure if you tried that one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use FileUtils.mv

I often do aliases like so:

```
require 'fileutils'

def mv(from, to)
  FileUtils.mv(from, to)
end
```

And inside the mv() method I do additional safeguards, i.e. if the file does not exist, if there is a lack of permissions and so forth.

If you then still have problems with filenames that have ' ' blank characters, try to put the file into a "" quote like:

```
your_target_location = "foo/bar bla"
```